# Stuck on solving the Minimal Spanning Tree problem

Tags: algorithm, graph, minimum-spanning-tree

I have reduced my problem to finding the minimal spanning tree in the graph. But I want to have one more constraint which is that *the total degree for each vertex shouldnt exceed a certain constant factor*. How do I model my problem? Is MST the wrong path?  Do you know any algorithms that will help me?

One more problem: My graph has duplicate edge weights so is there a way to count the number of unique MSTs? Are there algorithms that do this?

Thank You.

Edit: By degree, I mean the total number of edges connecting the vertex. By duplicate edge weight I mean that two edges have the same weight.

Comment: You can simply apply the kruskal algorithm, removing from the list the nedges that are connected to nodes with a maximum total degree, but I don't know if that determines an optimal solution (and if it determines a solution at all!)

Comment: Otherwise, you can apply the full kruskal algorithm and then use some local search techniques to get a valid spanning tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This paper shows how to find, in polynomial time, a spanning tree of maximum degree d + 1 that is at least as good as *any* spanning tree of maximum degree d: http://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/mohits/mbdst.pdf

//Edit The original link is currently inactive, try http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/80193/mbdst.pdf instead.

Comment: Havent read the entire thing but looks really useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's easy to prove that there may not be a solution: just make your input graph a tree that has a vertex with degree higher than your limit..

Comment: What if i put the load factor higher than the total weight constraint? That is I am willing to settle for the second minimal or even a third minimal. But that entails heuristics which may create more problem. For example, how do you decide which edge to replace? God is there another way to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't know; you haven't told us what your problem is :-)  But if you want a spanning tree with all vertices having deg <= n ... well, I can come up with a graph where any spanning tree (minimal or otherwise) includes at least one vertex with degree n+1.  Heuristics won't help you in that situation..

Answer (score 2):

Garey Johnson had this problem reduce to hamilton :( So this one helped. Approximating the first one: http://caislab.icu.ac.kr/Lecture/data/2003/spring/ice514/project/m03.ppt
However, better working models are appreciated...

Counting: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpanningTree.html . According to this, mathematica has a function. Any suggestions in this one?

Comment: Well, if you dig into the matrix tree theorem (referenced on mathworld), maybe you can find a way to systematically turn one spanning tree into another.  If you can do that, then you could cycle through the spanning trees until you find one that suits your purposes.  This is all a wild guess, though; no guarantees :-)